# Config MySQL to maximum speed and memory

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning, tuning

I have a server, 8 cores, 12 GB RAM. This server is only used to run MySQL. So, help me config `/etc/my.cnf` to maximum speed, memory for MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/) are some ideas. You can get a lot out of reading the book [High Performance MySQL](http://www.highperfmysql.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to your question. Tuning MySQL is very wokrload dependend.

- How your workload looks (mix of SELECTS/DMLs), query types, schema, indexing
- Storage engines used
- Working set size and database size
- Access patern generated by users.

[Here is link](https://serverfault.com/questions/118504/how-to-improve-mysql-insert-and-update-performance/118945#118945) to my answer to similar question. It has a lot of usefull links, which describe different aspects of tuning MySQL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL performance tuning is not a one day task, it is on going process. The best way is to monitor the performance of your MySQL and make the appropriate changes by tuning the mysql parameters. The below tools might help you.

**tuning-primer** 
**mysqlreport**

.These tools will analyze the current settings and will tell you whether you need to increase the value or decrease the same. E.g. InnoDB buffer pool, query_cache and many more.

I am using these tools and they are of great help.

Happy tunning...